# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not start Selenium session: Not Found

Tags: java, selenium, intellij-idea

I'm new at coding and I have run into this RunTimeException. I've already started up the localhost server at 4444, but I cannot manage to run this bit of code. Here is the code and the stackTrace:

```
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium;

import com.thoughtworks.selenium.Selenium;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Selenium selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost",4444,"*Firefox","http://gmail.com");

        selenium.start();

    }
}
```

And I get this exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not start Selenium session: Not Found

```
at com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium.start(DefaultSelenium.java:109)

at Main.main(Main.java:17)
```

Caused by: com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleniumException: Not Found

```
at com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.throwAssertionFailureExceptionOrError(HttpCommandProcessor.java:109)

at com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.getCommandResponseAsString(HttpCommandProcessor.java:180)

at com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.executeCommandOnServlet(HttpCommandProcessor.java:115)

at com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.doCommand(HttpCommandProcessor.java:98)

at com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.getString(HttpCommandProcessor.java:272)

at com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.start(HttpCommandProcessor.java:234)

at com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium.start(DefaultSelenium.java:100)
... 1 more
```

What is my issue here and why I cant run this code? 
Am I missing something? some plug-ing? some .jar file?

Please Help!!!

Thanks so much in advance for your answers!

Comment: Have you seen this: https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/2762 ?

Comment: Yes, i think i have the selenium server version 2.42.2 (thats my file name selenium-server-2.42.2.jar) and im using Firefox Quantum 64.0.2 (64-bits). Are they not compatible? In that case, how do i fix it?

Comment: I am not sure if they are compatible or not... but you can open an issue too...

Comment: you are trying to use the old selenium API.  use webdriver instead

Comment: Where can i get the newer selenium API and the correct webdriver?

Answer (score 0):

You will get the dependency details (.jar) of latest version of selenium webdriver on below link, add the dependency in your project and on project build required jar files will get downloaded in project class path.

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java

If you are not using any build tool then you can directly download the jar from https://www.seleniumhq.org/download/ link and import into your project.